# DevExpress Date not display correctly

Tags: devexpress, devextreme

**JS:**

```
var dataSource = [
    {date: new Date(1994,2,1), low: 24.00, high: 25.00, open: 25.00, close: 24.875},
    {date: new Date(1994,2,2), low: 23.625, high: 25.125, open: 24.00, close: 24.875},
    {date: new Date(1994,2,3), low: 26.25, high: 28.25, open: 26.75, close: 27.00},
    {date: new Date(1994,2,4), low: 26.50, high: 27.875, open: 26.875, close: 27.25},
    {date: new Date(1994,2,7), low: 26.375, high: 27.50, open: 27.375, close: 26.75},
    {date: new Date(1994,2,8), low: 25.75,high:  26.875, open: 26.75, close: 26.00},
    {date: new Date(1994,2,9), low: 25.75, high: 26.75, open: 26.125, close: 26.25},
    {date: new Date(1994,2,10), low: 25.75, high: 26.375, open: 26.375, close: 25.875},
    {date: new Date(1994,2,11), low: 24.875, high: 26.125, open: 26.00, close: 25.375},
    {date: new Date(1994,2,14), low: 25.125, high: 26.00, open: 25.625, close: 25.75},
    {date: new Date(1994,2,15), low: 25.875, high: 26.625, open: 26.125, close: 26.375},
    {date: new Date(1994,2,16), low: 26.25, high: 27.375, open: 26.25, close: 27.25},
    {date: new Date(1994,2,17), low: 26.875, high: 27.25, open: 27.125, close: 26.875},
    {date: new Date(1994,2,18), low: 26.375, high: 27.125, open: 27.00, close: 27.125},
    {date: new Date(1994,2,21), low: 26.75, high: 27.875, open: 26.875, close: 27.75},
    {date: new Date(1994,2,22), low: 26.75, high: 28.375, open: 27.50, close: 27.00},
    {date: new Date(1994,2,23), low: 26.875, high: 28.125, open: 27.00, close: 28.00},
    {date: new Date(1994,2,24), low: 26.25, high: 27.875, open: 27.75, close: 27.625},
    {date: new Date(1994,2,25), low: 27.50, high: 28.75, open: 27.75, close: 28.00},
    {date: new Date(1994,2,28), low: 25.75, high: 28.25, open: 28.00, close: 27.25},
    {date: new Date(1994,2,29), low: 26.375, high: 27.50, open: 27.50, close: 26.875},
    {date: new Date(1994,2,30), low: 25.75, high: 27.50, open: 26.375, close: 26.25},
    {date: new Date(1994,2,31), low: 24.75, high: 27.00, open: 26.50, close: 25.25},
];



$(function () {
    $("#chartContainer").dxChart({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        commonSeriesSettings: {
            type: 'stock'
        },
        series: {},
        argumentAxis: {
            tickInterval: { days: 2 },
            label: {
                format: 'dd/MM'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**View :**

[image]

**Markup :**

```
<div id="chartContainer" style="height:500px; max-width:700px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**Problem :**

Here my Date is `new Date(1994,2,1)` and in chart it display

> 02/03

And at the starting and ending extra date is display in chart like

> 28/2 And 30/3

So,What should i change to make my same date as in datasource ?

You can visit example by following link also
[DevExpress Link](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/dxChart/Configuration/argumentAxis/tickInterval/?search=argumentAxis%20tickinterval%20date&version=15_1&approach=jQuery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that JavaScript counts months from 0 to 11. January is 0. December is 11. That is why this happens. See [JavaScript Dates](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

You use a continuous axis, you can specify how far to extend the axis from its maximum and minimum values. Use the axis' [minValueMargin](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/dxChart/Configuration/argumentAxis?version=15_1#minValueMargin) and [maxValueMargin](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/dxChart/Configuration/argumentAxis?version=15_1#maxValueMargin) properties to do this.

Also check the valueMarginsEnabled property by setting it to false.

> By default, the axes extend slightly beyond their extrema. It prevents
> cutting off parts of the minimum and maximum series points. To disable
> this feature, set the valueMarginsEnabled option to false.

Regarding the date format, check the data/time style which chart gadget understand.

Comment: No you are going on wrong track.
It is not an issue of the space.
i have define date in datasource like "new Date(1994,2,1)"
here my month is 2 and date is 1.
But in if you compare date in argumentAxis of the chart.
It will display wrong date.

Comment: I am assign month 2 in data-source but in chart month is 3 increment by one.

Comment: Arguments interval is 2 and as per my understanding it is adjusting the scale intervals according to your value to fit all values in the particular scale. If you want to show your x axis values then other platform charts has custom x axis labels functionality..you can opt that option also if you your values must be shown in the x axis. Check the specified properties  it will let the chart to display x scale values according the data providing rather than auto scale the chart..

Comment: then why in data source my date is "new Date(1994,2,2)" and in chart date is "02/03".
why month is 3 instead of 2 ?

Comment: @Divyesh. First try to set the valueMarginsEnabled property to false. If it does not work then try another options..

Comment: yes i am agree with you the extra date is removed from starting and ending.
But have you seen my datasource ?
in that i have enter month as 2  for example: "new Date(1994,2,2)" but in chart date is display as a month of 3 for example:"02/03".

Comment: I have posted my answer please check.

Comment: Thank you for your support.

Comment: @Divyesh: It's good that you find the root cause of the behaviour. This will help other developers also.. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120564/discussion-between-divyesh-and-niranjan-kala).

Answer (score 0):

If you have no gaps in your dates try switching the `argumentAxis.type` to `discrete`.  When the axis is `continuous` the chart manipulates the raw data and changes the values used for the `argumentAxis`.